# Combine CSV files with the same column header

Tags: csv, merge

I have several CSV files I'd like to combine by matching column headers but still keep the unmatched columns, for example:

Input file1.csv:

```
col1,col2,col3,col5
a,b,c,d
d,e,b,g
c,a,d,h
```

Input file2.csv:

```
col1,col3,col4,col5
g,d,b,c
o,e,x,h
b,n,w,e
```

Desired output:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
a,b,c,,d
d,e,b,,g
c,a,d,,h
g,,d,b,c
o,,e,x,h
b,,n,w,e
```

Comment: I assume you mean CSV files! CVS is a version control system

Comment: maybe have a look at something like https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv for working with csv file directly.  either that or import into an RDBMS like Postgres, or maybe something like Pandas in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for several OSs):

```bash
mlr --csv unsparsify file1.csv file2.csv
```

```
col1,col2,col3,col5,col4
a,b,c,d,
d,e,b,g,
c,a,d,h,
g,,d,c,b
o,,e,h,x
b,,n,e,w
```

**remark:** The columns are outputted in the order in which they first appear; if need be, you can specify a custom ordering, but you'll need to know the column names in advance.

Comment: Excellent! Worked excatly as intended, many thanks!