# How to combine CSV files without using pandas

Tags: python, csv

I have 3 csv files that I need to merge

all the 3 files have the first three columns being equal while like name, age, sex but other columns are different for all.

I am new to python. I need assistance on this. I can comprehend any code written. Thanks

I have tried some codes but not working

```
file 1
firstname,secondname,age,address,postcode,height
gdsd,gas,uugd,gusa,uuh,hhuuw
kms,kkoil,jjka,kja,kaja,loj
iiow,uiuw,iue,oijw,uow,oiujw
ujis,oiiw,ywuq,sax,cxv,ywf

file 2
firstname,secondname,age,home-town,spousename,marital_staus
gdsd,gas,uugd,vbs,owu,nsvc
kms,kkoil,jjka,kja,kaja,loj
iiow,uiuw,iue,xxfaf,owuq,pler
ujis,oiiw,ywuq,gfhd,lzac,oqq

   file 3
firstname,secondname,age,drive,educated,
gdsd,gas,uugd,no,yes
kms,kkoil,jjka,no,no
iiow,uiuw,iue,yes,no
ujis,oiiw,ywuq,yes,yes
```

desired result

```
firstname,secondname,age,hometown,spousename,marital_status,adress,post_code,height,drive,educated
```

note that `firstname,secondname,age` is the same across the 3 tables

I need valid codes please

Comment: What does "merge/combine" mean? Can you provide an example with two sample files and the expected result of merging/combining them?

Comment: There are three csv files, each of them have their first three columns being equal but other columns are different for each of them. I want to write the 3 files in a new file such that the equal column will not appear thrice but once, then other unequal ones will then come in as different columns in the new file.

Comment: What I mean with "sample" example is this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75069501/3387716

Comment: I have just edited it, please check

Comment: Where are the pandas?

Comment: Pandas usage not allowed

Comment: Is the order of entries in the different CSV files identical, as suggested by your samples? Is each CSV file guaranteed to have the same (number & identifying values) entries? If so, then a solution is pretty simple. If one or both of these are not given, then it will become a bit more involved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it feels like OP's asking for others to do his homework

Comment: @ThenewGuy If the goal is just to generate a "merged" CSV without doing anything else then there's quite a few other tools that can do the merging with just a switch in the command-line. So, why do you need to do it in Python? Is it a **homework**? In any case, you have to provide your code, pointing-out where you need our help.

Comment: @Fravadona: it being potentially homework isn't in itself sufficient reason to close this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) "Needs clarity or details" or maybe "more focus" could arguably be applicable here, but just "might be homework" is not a reason to close.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I don’t discriminate against homework questions, and this question might not even be one. It’s just that I feel a "do my job in my place" vibe from the question

Comment: Thank all. I have been able to do this my self. I read them all as a list of dictionaries. It was easier looping over list creating a merger file

Comment: @ThenewGuy I added an answer for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic solution for concatenating CSV files that have heterogeneous headers with Python.

What you need to do first is to read the header of each CSV file for determining the "unique" field names.

Then, you just have to read each input record and output it while transforming it to match the new header (which is the unique fields).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

paths = [ 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv' ]

fieldnames = set()
for p in paths:
    with open(p,'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        fieldnames.update( next(reader) )

with open('combined.csv', 'w') as o:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(o, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for p in paths:
        with open(p,'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            writer.writerows( reader )
```

**remark:** I open the files twice, so it won't work for inputs that are streams (for ex. `sys.stdin`)